# Why does the confidence interval change in poisson.test() and binom.test() based on the alternative hypothesis?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

For example:

```
poisson.test(x = 170,T = 70,r = 3,alternative = "two.sided",conf.level = .95)

    Exact Poisson test

data:  170 time base: 70
number of events = 170, time base = 70, p-value = 0.005157
alternative hypothesis: true event rate is not equal to 3
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.077216 2.822335
sample estimates:
event rate 
  2.428571
```

gives me the answer I would expect for a 95% CI. But if I change the alternate to a one-tail test:

```
poisson.test(x = 170,T = 70,r = 3,alternative = "less",conf.level = .95)

    Exact Poisson test

data:  170 time base: 70
number of events = 170, time base = 70, p-value = 0.002502
alternative hypothesis: true event rate is less than 3
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.000000 2.758037
sample estimates:
event rate 
  2.428571
```

We can see that the CI has changed drastically when I changed only the alternative hypothesis. Something similar happens in binom.test() as well. In the Biometrika article cited in the function (https://doi-org.colorado.idm.oclc.org/10.1093/biomet/26.4.404) I don't see any mention of changing the limits based on the alternative, and I can't think of any reason you would want to.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-sided hypothesis testing, such as in your second example

> alternative hypothesis: true event rate is less than 3

result in a one-sided confidence interval.  One-sided confidence intervals are maybe unusual, so seems unfamiliar. For a discussion see for instance [Inverting a hypothesis test: nitpicky detail](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61006/inverting-a-hypothesis-test-nitpicky-detail)

One-sided confidence intervals follows naturally when constructing confidence intervals (CI) by inverting a hypothesis test, see [Inverting a hypothesis test: nitpicky detail](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61006/inverting-a-hypothesis-test-nitpicky-detail).  The idea is to include in the CI parameter values that cannot be rejected using the test.  But the rejection region for a test will be different for one-sided and two-sided tests, so the resulting CI must be different. For details see the above linked post.

A more detailed discussion is at [Intuition for inverting one sided hypothesis tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599523/intuition-for-inverting-one-sided-hypothesis-tests)

Comment: Hunh, well doing some further reading based on your comment I found some statisticians that do this. I had never heard of it in almost 30 years of doing and teaching stats. I can kind of see the reasoning if you treat a CI as in inverted hypothesis test. It also neatly addresses the inherent concern with one-tail tests. But in the applied world I live in, the CI being, "the interval that captures the true population mean x% of the time" is more practical and would be two-sided to be useful. Thank you very much for this new piece of knowledge! I'll think on this some more!